Deleting files from dom using angular componet load
this.filesToRemove.forEach(filePath => {
      // Handle CSS files
      const linkElement = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="stylesheet"]'))
        .find(link => (link as HTMLLinkElement).href.includes(filePath)) as HTMLLinkElement;

      if (linkElement && linkElement.parentNode) {
        this.removedElements.push(linkElement);
        linkElement.parentNode.removeChild(linkElement);
      }

      // Handle JS files
      const scriptElement = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('script'))
        .find(script => (script as HTMLScriptElement).src.includes(filePath)) as HTMLScriptElement;

      if (scriptElement && scriptElement.parentNode) {
        this.removedElements.push(scriptElement);
        scriptElement.parentNode.removeChild(scriptElement);
      }
    })

i have tried deleting files from dom

So, what's happening? Does anything happen or do you get some kind of error? Are you sure that it's not working because of that piece of code or maybe something surrounding it doesn't work?
